# Why does Hive return FAILED: SemanticException...Unable To Instantiate

Tags: hadoop, terminal, hive

I have installed Hive, added it to PATH and am able to open it using the `hive` command in Terminal.

However, when I attempt to run a basic command such as

`SHOW TABLES;`

I am presented with the error:

`FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient`

The instructions I am following do not suggest that anything has to be instantiated.

For reference, I am using the book Hadoop: The Definitive Guide (4th Edition) and running it locally on my machine.

When running JPS the following services are running:

2528 DataNode
7232 RunJar
2441 NameNode
7401 Jps
2634 SecondaryNameNode
282 
2842 NodeManager
2751 ResourceManager

Answer (score 4):

I fixed by removing the derby database files

```
rm -rf $HIVE_HOME/bin/metastore_db
```

and

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this problem by initializing the schema. I am surprised it is not mentioned anywhere.

To initialize the schema:

1. Navigate to your Hive installation folder
2. [install folder]/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
3. Next you should receive some messages confirming

   Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
   Metastore connection User:   APP
   Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.3.0
   Initialization script hive-schema-2.3.0.derby.sql
   Initialization script completed
   schemaTool completed
4. Start hive
5. Run any basic commands to determine Hive is functioning such as `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: Hadoop Definitive Guide book was written before Hive 2.3, but the Hive installation Wiki does indeed mention initialization of the metastore